# Trying to get property of non-object en PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo que arreglar el siguiente `script`:

```
<?php 
if($_POST["nombre"]!="" && $_POST["id_proveedor"]!=""){
    include "../../php/conexion.php";
    $params = array_filter($_POST);

    $id_proveedor = "SELECT id FROM proveedores WHERE nombre = \"$_POST[id_proveedor]\"";

    $result_id_proveedor = $con->query($id_proveedor);
    $obj = $result_id_proveedor->fetch_object();
    $params['id_proveedor'] = $obj->id_proveedor;

    $params['created_at'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $fields = implode(',', array_keys($params));
    $values = '"'.  implode('","',array_values ($params))  . '"';

    $sql = "INSERT INTO marcas ($fields) VALUES ($values)";
    $query = $con->query($sql);
    echo $sql;
    print "<script>alert(\"Registro exitoso.\");window.location='../marcas.php';</script>";
     }

?>
```

La idea es que inserte en la tabla **marcas** el nombre de una marca, una descripción y, sobre todo, el **id** del proveedor que vendería esta marca, que se encuentra en una tabla llamada **proveedores**.

El dato del **id** lo recojo del siguiente `select`:

```
<label for="id_proveedor">Proveedor:</label>
<select class="form-control" name="id_proveedor" id="id_proveedor" required
     <option value="">Seleccione:</option>
     <?php
          include_once "../php/conexion.php";
          $query = $con -> query("SELECT * FROM proveedores");
          while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
               echo '<option id="id_proveedor" value="'.$valores['id'].'">'.$valores['nombre'].'</option>';
               }
     ?>
</select>
```

Este `select` obtiene los nombres de los proveedores, pero la idea es que tome e inserte sus respectivos **id** en la tabla de las marcas.

El resultado de correr el `script` es el siguiente:

> Notice: Trying to get property 'id_proveedor' of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\estudiomanager.com\system\productos\php\registro_marcas.php
>   on line 10

La línea 10 corresponde a **$params['id_proveedor'] = $obj->id_proveedor;**.
El `var_dump` de este **$params** me da NULL.

Además, carga todos los datos pero el id del proveedor, queda en 0.
Este es el `echo` de **$sql**:

> INSERT INTO marcas (nombre,id_proveedor,descripcion,created_at) VALUES
>   ("Juana de Arco","","Marca de prueba","2019-06-02 04:48:00")

No me estaría tomando correctamente el dato del **id** de la tabla de PROVEEDORES para poder volcarlo en la tabla de MARCAS.

Comment: 1.- El `id_proveedor` en el option es totalmente innecesario e incorrecto. 2.- envias por el formulario el `id_proveedor` que entiendo este debe ser in entero, pero en la primera consulta la estas comparando con el nombre, esto claramente no te devolverá un id. 3.- si el punto 2 estuviera correcto, para que consultas el `id` del proveedor si ya viene como parametro del formulario?

Comment: Hola, gracias por comentar. 1. Puse el `id_proveedor` en el option, para que luego, el script PHP reconozca que ese dato, tiene que ser el que vuelque a la base de datos. 2. Claramente, no hice un `echo` de esa consulta, y efectivamente, devuelve el número del `id` y no el `nombre`, como creí que lo hacía. 3. Estoy haciendo toda es consulta de más sin ningún sentido, la idea era que compare el nombre, con el id en la tabla de proveedores, y si coincidían. entonces vuelque el id en la tabla de marcas. Pero eso ya lo hizo en el `POST` de arriba como parámetro del formulario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que no existe ningún campo con el nombre de  $obj->id_proveedor en tu primera select, lo que tienes en tu select solo es $obj->id

Creo que tu consulta `select id proveedores` esta de mas ya que el id ya llega por $_POST["id_proveedor"], solo deberías validar los datos e insertarlos

```
<?php 
if($_POST["nombre"]!="" && $_POST["id_proveedor"]!=""){
    include "../../php/conexion.php";
    $params = array_filter($_POST);

    //$sqlProvedores = "SELECT id FROM proveedores WHERE id = \"$_POST[id_proveedor]\"";//este codigo esta de mas ya que ya tienes el id que llega por POST


    //$result_id_proveedor = $con->query($sqlProvedores);
    //if($result_id_proveedor){
    //  $obj = $result_id_proveedor->fetch_object();
    //$params['id_proveedor'] = $obj->id_proveedor;//este esta de mas ya que el valos ya se fue asignado

      $params['created_at'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

      $fields = implode(',', array_keys($params));
      $values = '"'.  implode('","',array_values ($params))  . '"';

      $sql = "INSERT INTO marcas ($fields) VALUES ($values)";
      $query = $con->query($sql);
      echo $sql;
      print "<script>alert(\"Registro exitoso.\");window.location='../marcas.php';</script>";
   // }
  }

?>
```

Recomendable usar ajax para separar tu código Backend y Frontend y evitar mesclar los scripts

Comment: Funcionó, directamente borré la parte del script que pusiste como comentarios e inserta todo correctamente en la tabla. Ahora lo que tengo que hacer es que este mismo script lea si nombre de la marca ya se repite para ese proveedor selecccionado, y generar un alert y no lo guarde.